# Query an aborted CronTrigger

Tags: soql, scheduled-apex

So I can query CronTrigger and see it's status, previous runs, next run time, etc.

However, if I abort the job from SF UI, the record gets deleted. Now, there is some info on AsyncApexJob, but the Id there is different and I can't figure out how to relate the two.

Any ideas?

Comment: You will need to store the cronJobId, returned from the system.schedule() call before deleting the CronJob from the SF UI. Once, the job gets deleted it does not show up from the UI but its corresponding AsyncApexJob record can be retrieved using a Soql with filters such as Id = CronJobId AND Status = 'Aborted'.

Comment: @JigarShah `System.schedule()` return Id of type CronTrigger rather than AsyncApexJob (that's returned by `Database.executeBatch()`).
What I am trying to find where these two objects are related anyhow.